# Can I use VBA to detect if a number is stored as text in a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

I am thinking somehting along the lines of:

```
if Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@" AND test to show that the content of A1 can be a number Then
    Debug.Print("A1 is a number stored as text")
end if
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Can I use VBA to detect if a number is stored as text in a cell?

Let me play too :)

To do an exact test to check if a number is stored as text in a cell, use this

```
Sub Sample()
    If (Range("A1").NumberFormat = "@" And IsNumeric(Range("A1"))) Or _
    (Range("A1").PrefixCharacter = "'" And IsNumeric(Range("A1"))) Then
       Debug.Print ("A1 is a number stored as text")
    End If
End Sub
```

This will take care of scenarios like this

[image]

Note that in the first cell the numberformat is `General` and the number is stored as Text using `'`

**EDIT**:

To demonstrate this a little further. We will convert the above sub to a UDF

```
Function IsNumberStoredAsText(Rng As Range)
    IsNumberStoredAsText = "Number is not stored as text"

    If (Rng.NumberFormat = "@" And IsNumeric(Rng)) Or _
    (Rng.PrefixCharacter = "'" And IsNumeric(Rng)) Then
       IsNumberStoredAsText = "Number stored as text"
    End If
End Function
```

Now using it in the worksheet

[image]

Comment: Plus one for the `PrefixCharacter`. there's still so much much more to learn.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, see my [test workbook](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2lh1hmafp98erm1/simoco3.xlsm). Unfortunatelly your solution doesn't work in one case - when number stores as `General` without `PrefixCharacter`. You should check it in your UDF as well. (You can get nubers formated as `General` if you copy cells with `Text` format and then replace `Text` format to `General`)

Comment: Actually, if you copies `Text` cells with numbers, and pastes them, numbers will still stores as text even if you change `Text` format to `Nubmer format` untill you press F2 and ENTER (you can check it in my test workbook). So, there should be more complex check. It's also possible to have cells with `Number format` but with numbers stores as text

Comment: @simoco: Good Point. Once you manually convert the format of the cell to say number or even date then it is difficult to check if the text is stored as number or not. The same will not work with your code as well. And i cannot think of any other method to check if the number is stored as text in such a case.

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I have an idea, but not sure it's possible. Can we get error list of cells? (I mean if the number stores as text there is a green corner in the left top of cell and if we select this cell the yellow exclamation icon appears to the left of cell, so if we click on this icon - excel says that there is an error and suggest you to convert text to number). Hope you understand what I mean:)

Comment: @simoco: I already thought of that but that is highly unreliable as that green triangle depends on the error checking options. If the Error checking is not on then you will not see the green triangle :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout, you are right:) But if this option is on, it would pe the closest solution:)

Comment: @simoco: And hence it is unreliable :)

Comment: @simoco: Superb! :) Now all you need to do is combine all the 3 in the IF and you have it

Comment: @SiddharthRout, I've tested it and there is no need to combine anything. `Rng.Value + "0" <> Rng.Value` works in all cases:)

Answer (score 9):

**UPD:**

**All solutions are good, but doen't work in next cases:**

It's also possible to have cells with `Number format` (or any other format) but with numbers stores as text (you can see it in my test wotkbook). Imagine the situation when you have number in cell with `Text` format and then you change `Text` format to the `Nubmer format` (in cells properties or using "Format" combobox in the Ribbon). Your value would be still stored as text (despite the fact that excel says that it stores in `Number Format`) untill you press <kbd>F2</kbd> and <kbd>ENTER</kbd> (you can check it in my test workbook). *You can simply reproduce this behavior:* change format of cell to `Text`, then enter value (i.e. 123), and then change format of cell to `Number Format` (exactly in this order). Now your value stored as text but has `Number Format`.

**So, examine `Range.NumberFormat` is a wrong way.**

Here is [**Test workbook**](https://www.dropbox.com/s/fk4wrh17mibs0x3/simoco5.xlsm)

**There is a very simple and elegant way to detect if a number stored as text or as number:**

```
Function IsNumberStoredAsText(Rng As Range)
    If Not IsNumeric(Rng) Then
        IsNumberStoredAsText = "NOT number"
        Exit Function
    End If

    IsNumberStoredAsText = "Number NOT stored as text"

    If Rng.Value + "0" <> Rng.Value Then
       IsNumberStoredAsText = "Number stored as text"
    End If
End Function
```

**How it works:**

Let cell `A1` contains number "123" *stored as text*. In this case `Range("A1").Value + "0"` would concatenate two strings and return "1230", but if `A1` contains number 123 *stored as number*,  `"0"` would be casted to `0` and `Range("A1").Value + "0"` would return number 123

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: + 1 Actually answers the question.

Answer (score 9):

There is actually a more convenient way to detect whether or not a cell contains a number stored as text :

```
    If Range("A1").Errors.Item(xlNumberAsText).Value = True Then
       MsgBox "Number Stored As Text"
    Else
       MsgBox "Number Not Stored As Text"
    End If
```

A.

Comment: I was looking for this - this should probably be the answer - I'm going to test it but thanks! Do you know if there is a way to use `SpecialCells` to basically get all the cells that have this particular error? I imagine there is - Thinking of a way to automatically convert all numeric cells stored as text without looping through all cells.

Answer (score 5):

The test you seek is

```
ISNUMERIC(...)
```

From Excel help:

> Returns a Boolean value indicating whether an expression can be evaluated as a number.

Comment: Chris, I might be wrong but the actual question is not to check if the cell has a numeric value but to check if the numeric value is stored as text.

Comment: @SiddharthRout i think he just supplied what the OP is lacking in his code. actually this is the only question `test to show that the content of A1 can be a number` :)

Comment: @SiddharthRout `isnumeric` tests if it's parameter _can be_ a number. This includes where it's a string that looks like a number.

Comment: @chrisneilsen: True but just ISNUMERIC(...)` will give a `False Positive` for cases where the cell's format is number and it contains a number. Like I mentioned, my understanding of the question is `to detect if a number is stored as text in a cell`

Comment: @SiddharthRout now I see your question!  The op said _AND test to show ..._ my answer was meant to indicate that part of the test, not the whole `if` (But your A is even more complete)

Comment: `my answer was meant to indicate that part of the test, not the whole if` Oh I see :) Deserves a + 1 Then. But it would be good if you mention that in your answer as well. People like me can get easily confused... lol

Answer (score 1):

I am sorry for the late answer (I am new on SO), but I think the correct answer is still missing. So I am afraid you are wrong too, simoco.

For example, whenever I reference to a number in a pivot table where it is stored as text (source might be another table, or database), your function does not work.
My solution seems to work in all cases. Excel already has a function for this which can be used as formula: `=ISTEXT(reference)`.

As the OP wants to use VBA, the solution is:
**`Application.WorksheetFunction.IsText (reference)`**, which returns `True` or `False`.